# Spinner getSelectedItem() returning null

Tags: android, spinner

I am getting NULL pointer exception while trying to access getSelectedItem().toString() on spn_make.

```
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(InfoActivity.this);
            spn_make.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.i("Count", spn_make.getAdapter().getCount()+"");
            spn_make.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> a, View v,
                                int pos, long arg3) {
                            Toast.makeText(InfoActivity.this, spn_make.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> a) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
```

Please can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve selected item you have to write

```
a.getItemAtPosition(pos)
```

instead of `spn_make.getSelectedItem()`

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) is the documentation for reference

change this line of code

```
Toast.makeText(InfoActivity.this, spn_make.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to this :

```
Toast.makeText(InfoActivity.this, a.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I tried spn_make.getItemAtPosition(pos) instead of spn_make.getSelectedItem(), still it is throwing null pointer exception

Comment: '@Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> a, View v,
                                int pos, long arg3) {
                            Toast.makeText(InfoActivity.this, a.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }'

Comment: @androidDev i'm also facing the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (Spinner.getSelectedItem() == null) {
            return;
        }else {
          Textview  tv = Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }
```

Comment: You might like to read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). In addition, while this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.

Answer (score 0):

it work best...

```
auto_comp_type.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override           
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
               Toast.makeText(Screen_Add_Payment.this, "Clicked"+adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).